# reproduce R function call with text

Tags: r, debugging, dput

in an application I use `RODBC` to access a database. Specifically I call a function like this: `sqlQuery(conn, qry)`, where `qry` is a string, and `conn` is a `RODBC` connection object.

Is it possible to paste this into a file in such a way that if I copy and paste the file contents into the terminal, I will reproduce the exact function call?

For example, if I make a dataframe: `df <- data.frame(test = c(1, 2, 3))`, I can call `dput(df)`, which will return: `structure(list(frank = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))`

If I copy and paste that into the terminal, I will get the original dataframe.

It would be really convienient for debugging if I could do something like this for `sqlQuery(conn, qry)`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: something that I can copy and paste into r studio terminal and produce the same error without loading everything up manually (database connection, query string, ect...)

Comment: If you're using RStudio, maybe look into making a custom [snippet](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `dput` works Ok for your objects, and that we can assume that any required libraries are loaded and/or functions defined, why not just build the function call string like this:

Define 'fput' function to generate pastable string that will replicate a function call:

```
fput = function( fun_string, ... ) {
    args=as.list(match.call(expand.dots=F))[["..."]]
    arg_strings=lapply(args,function(arg) capture.output(do.call(dput,list(arg),envir=parent.frame())))
    arg_string=paste(arg_strings,collapse=",")
    paste(fun_string,"(",arg_string,")")
}
```

Example:

Sample data:

```
a=1:10
b=a^2
```

Sample function call to replicate as pastable string:

```
plot(a,b)
```

Call fput():

```
fput( "plot", a, b )
```

Output:

```
[1] "plot ( 1:10,c(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100) )"
```

Check: copy-paste of output generates same result as plot(a,b)